# which python does not align with sys.executable in a virtualenv

Tags: python, linux, virtualenv

```
(ENV) willy@willy-X555LB:~/ENV/bin$ which python
/home/willy/ENV/bin/python
(ENV) willy@willy-X555LB:~/ENV/bin$ python
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.executable)
/usr/bin/python3
```

What happen? I'm using Ubuntu 16.

I created the virtualenv with the following command

`$ virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 ENV`

Comment: Make `ls -la /home/willy/ENV/bin/python` and print here

Comment: just in this virtualenv, or in any virtualenv you create?

Comment: @RedEyed
/home/willy/ENV/bin/python -> python3

Comment: @Kos every virtualenv created with the following command.
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 ENV

Comment: Have you tried creating the virtualenv with `python3 -m venv ENV`?

Comment: The  command that I used to create the virtualenv is updated to the post.